# Странно возникшая ошибка CS0246: Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен

Tags: c#, asp.net

У меня есть проект Domain, в папке Entities которого лежат модели для бд.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В другом проекте у меня определен ApplicationDbContext, в котором используются эти модели в качестве типа данных у DbSet. Директива `using Domain.Entities` указана в начале файла.

```
        public DbSet<Block> Blocks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Guideline> Guidelines { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Graduate> Graduates { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Patner> Patners { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GuidelineVacant> GuidelineVacants { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GuidelineForm> Forms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Exam> Exams { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FileModel> FileModels { get; set; }
```

Проблема в том, что до этого была только одна модель - Block, - и только с ней был DbSet в файле ApplicationDbContext, и всё прекрасно запускалось. После добавления остальных сущностей проект перестал запускаться с ошибкой, указанной в топике, для каждой строки, где DbSet'ы используются с другими моделями. Причём никаких ошибок перед запуском проекта он не показывает. Всё чисто. В чём может быть проблема?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вероятно у вас есть другой тип `Block` в проекте с `ApplicationDbContext`. Нажмите по нему F12.

Comment: Объекты предметной области (Domain) и сущности базы данных (Entity) - это две разных области. Нельзя использовать одни в качестве других. Для использования в базе данных определите свои собственные сущности в проекте с ApplicationDbContext. При необходимости конвертируйте одни в другие - это стандартная практика при передаче данных из одной области/слоя (tier/layer) в другую.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, нет, ```Block``` у меня определен только в ```Domain```. А по поводу конвертации - классы между проектами используются спокойно же. А тут же именно, что простое использование классов между проектами